# npm - how to upgrade transitive dependencies to a specific newer version? (inorder to fix cve)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Below are the packages i need to upgrade.

i tried to update the `version`, `signature` of below packages in `package-lock.json`.

Once i do `npm i` after modifying `package-lock.json`, the changes done in  `package-lock.json` disappears.

[image]

As of today, `xmldom` npm package cannot be upgraded to [0.7.0](https://github.com/xmldom/xmldom/discussions/270) as the maintainers are facing some problem in pushing the version [0.7.0](https://github.com/xmldom/xmldom/discussions/270) to npm registry

i have tried out the answers mentioned in other stackoverflow posts, but it doesnot seem to fix my issue even though the reported issues are the same.

if there are any standard approaches to solve this, kindly share it.

Please suggest how to resolve this

**package.json**

```
  {
  "name": "qabot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.slack.js",
  "nodemonConfig": {
    "ignore": [
      "config/*",
      "tempdirectory/*"
    ]
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.18.4"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@slack/bolt": "^3.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "botbuilder": "^4.12.0",
    "convert-excel-to-json": "^1.7.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "node-vault": "^0.9.22",
    "node-vault-client": "^0.5.6",
    "qs": "^6.10.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: It would make it easier to answer if you shared your `package.json` file.

Comment: @Trott i have updated `package.json` in question. Please check

Comment: From my experience, we simply installed required version of the package using `npm i` .In most cases it replaced vulnerable one, and after patch we uninstalled previous one.

Comment: please confirm if it would work for transitive dependencies as well (as i have mentioned in the question)? because i tried it  and was unsuccessful @Drag13

Comment: Thanks for pinging me. I've just checked on the create-react-app (it has 3 vulnerabilities for now, perfect candidate for double check). So I've tried my approach and found that it fails. I also tried some other tricks (except manual changing .lock file) and nothing worked. So seems that your question is still unresolved.

Comment: @Drag13 thank you for responding. i'm not sure if there is some standard approach inorder to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of options for this. The first thing I would do is determine if any of these warnings are even relevant.

In your case, the `xmldom` dependency is itself a dependency of `adal-node` which is "for node.js applications to authenticate to AAD in order to access AAD protected web resources". If you're not doing anything remotely like that, then chances are you don't need to worry about it too much. (You can take extra steps anyway if you like, such as removing `node_modules/xmldom` or replacing it with 0.7.0.)

The other two vulnerabilities are in dependencies of `convert-excel-to-json`.

One is `yargs-parser`, a command-line arguments parser. If you are not using the command-line for `convert-excel-to-json`, or not allowing users to affect the arguments passed to the CLI, then you are likely unaffected by that one.

The last is a denial of service in `xlsx`. This one is a dependency you are likely using as you are using the `convert-excel-to-json` module directly. (If you're not, `npm uninstall convert-excel-to-json` to resolve.) If you are in control of the .xlsx file contents (and the user has no ability to affect the contents), then you are likely not vulnerable. You may also decide that a denial of service is not something you're worried about, depending on the use case. (If the bot or whatever you're building only has one or two users and it's you and your friend or whatever, you're both unlikely to intentionally DoS your own service.)

If any of these do affect you and are significant issues for you, then you have lots of things you might try:

- Check relevant issue trackers to see if a fix is in the works.
- Manually update dependencies to supposedly-incompatible versions (but only if you have good test coverage).
- Look for alternative dependencies.
- Fork the existing dependencies and use your fork.
- Other options I'm not thinking of right now, many of which might be better than all of the above.

Comment: could you please let me know the steps on how to update dependencies manually?